# Impossible to change timeout on Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I have an issue with Azure function app

I have one with an App Service Plan and I cannot go over the default 5 min timeout. I published this function from Visual Studio

Here is my host.json :

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

I also tried to create a slot in Azure and publish on it with the Host Key functionTimeout defined but it's not working neither

I am a bit lost as I tried all solutions found here or on internet

Thanks a lot
Matthieu

Comment: Have you tried to modify the functionTimeout in your function app host.json on Azure portal ?
And may I know the original version of your function app, do you want to change the version from 1 to 2 at the same time ?

Comment: @Hury I have changed the host.json in my code in Visual Studio, I can't change it on Azure portal as it's a read only (published via VS). It's a new function directly in v2

Answer (score 1):

For now, host.json is the only way I know to change the timeout. So if you could change it cause the read only mode, there are two ways to edit.

One is use App service Editor to edit it, another is go your Function **kudu** site, under **wwwroot** folder edit the host.json file.

[image]

**Note:** From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout) and the [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17305ddc-07b2-436c-881b-286d1744c98f/503-errors-with-large-pdf-file?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) by David we could know,

> There is a 230 second (i.e. a little less than 4 mins) timeout for requests that are not sending any data back. After that, the client gets the 500 you saw, even though in reality the request is allowed to continue server side.

Comment: it was an issue with the 230 seconds indeed

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check if host.json is updated or not on your function app?
[image]

Or try editing host.json from portal and test

Comment: Hi Agrawal,
Yes the host.json is updated in Azure portal. I cannot edit online as it's a package deployed via Visual Studio